# C#. не получает cookies

Tags: c#

Делаю авторизацию. После ввода логина и пароля со страницы логина отправляются cookies и на странице user принимаются и проверяются. Если данные соответствуют, то пользователь остается на странице. Если нет, его возвращает. Проблема в том, что на страницу пользователя cookies не приходят. При отладке в них пустое значение.

UDP:Проблема оказалась в том, что почему-то не удалялись старые cookie и он все время подгружал их с пустыми значениями. Почистил и проблема пропала. Код рабочий

Код функции что отправляет cookies:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> db = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        SqlCommand getUsersCredCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Login], [Pass] FROM [Users]", sqlConnection);
        SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;
        try
        {
            sqlReader = await getUsersCredCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while (await sqlReader.ReadAsync())
            {
                db.Add(Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Login"]), Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Pass"]));
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlReader != null)
            {
                sqlReader.Close();
            }
        }
        if (db.Keys.Contains(TextBox1.Text) && TextBox2.Text == db[TextBox1.Text])
        {
            HttpCookie login = new HttpCookie("login", TextBox1.Text);
            HttpCookie sign  = new HttpCookie("sign", SignGenerator.GetSign(TextBox1.Text + "bytepp"));

            Response.Cookies.Add(login);
            Response.Cookies.Add(sign);
            Response.Redirect("UserPage.aspx", false);

        }
```

Код функции, что принимает и обрабатывает cookies:

```
        HttpCookie login = Request.Cookies["login"];
        HttpCookie sign  = Request.Cookies["sign"];
        if (login != null && sign != null)
        {
            if (sign.Value == SignGenerator.GetSign(login.Value + "bytepp"))
            {
                Label1.Text = login.Value;

                return;
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
```

Код SignGenerator:

```
    public static string GetSign(string s) {
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] hash = provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s));

        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).ToLower().Replace("-", "");
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте поглядеть что получаете через `MessageBox.Show("Login: " + login + ", sign: " + sign);`

Comment: А если сначала все куки в массив через `Request.Cookies.AllKeys` и посмотреть что приходит, а уже от этого плясать.

Comment: Проблема оказалась в том, что почему-то не удалялись старые cookie и он все время подгружал их с пустыми значениями. Почистил и проблема пропала. Код рабочий